# rails 3 how to limit relationships to 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, callback

I have Users Bands and Codes.

A user creates a code and that code has a user_id and a band_id.

I have a before save callback generating the code.

```
before_create :generate_code

  private
    def generate_code      
      self.code = SecureRandom.hex(3)
    end
```

I need to add a check, if code exists with user_id and band_id, return false

That way a user will only have one code per band

thoughts?

Comment: i believe SecureRandom is always unique. i don't think you need to make that check.

Comment: It is unique but its doesn't keep a user from generating another code.

Comment: attr_protected then. users won't be able to update this attribute unless you do it programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to keep generating until you get a valid code, try:

```
def generate_code
  begin
    self.code = SecureRandom.hex(3)
  end while User.exists?(:code => self[:code])
end
```

if you just want to try one code, and return false, try:

```
def generate_code
  self.code = SecureRandom.hex(3)
  return false if User.exists?(:code => self[:code])
end
```

Note: change "User" to whatever your relation you're checking the collision in :)

Alternatively, you could just try `validates :code, :uniqueness => true` or something similar :)